# Laravel - set variable globally

Tags: php, variables, laravel, laravel-4, global-variables

I have a few vars in my app that I would like to share through multiple views and requests. Basically I have a custom Layout which I load like that:

```
@section('stylesheet')
    {{ HTML::style(URL::to('custom_stylesheet/'.$slug)) }}
@stop
```

I somehow have to send the "slug" var to every request and action and/or controller I need and I need a few. It's a shop from a startpage to checkout, last step.

How can I achieve that? Is View::share() a solution or a cookie?

The URL structure is like that:

```
www.domain.tld/name/{client_slug}/{event_slug}/<all other variables>
```

like /overview or /checkout or /details/{event_id}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to specify views, use a View Composer:

```
View::composer(['view-a', 'view-b'], function($view)
{
    $client_slug = 'whatever you need to do to calculate the slug';

    $view->with('client_slug', $client_slug);

    $view->with('event_slug', $event_slug);

    $view->with('variable1', $variable1);
});
```

Or, as you said, View Share to share with all of them:

```
View::share('client_slug', $client_slug);
```

You can create a file for this purpose, something like `app/composers.php` and load it in your `app/start/global.php`:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

And you can consider using Session vars too, which keeps data through multiple requests:

```
Session::put('client_slug', $client_slug);
```

And get it with

```
$client slug = Session::put('client_slug');
```

But if this is a View thing only, View Composers are the way to go.

Using Session and View Composer them togheter is simple, you can set in one request:

```
Session::put('client_slug', $client_slug);
```

And in the next request you can send it to your views:

```
View::composer(['view-a', 'view-b'], function($view)
{
    if (Session::has('client_slug'))
    {
        $view->with('client_slug', Session::get('client_slug'));
    }
    else
    {
        $view->with('client_slug', 'default-slug-or-whatever-you-would-do');
    }
});
```

Comment: But how is it possible to SET this variables? Can I grab them on the frist request and save them into the composer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do this:

```
if (Cache::has('slug'))
{
    View::share('slug', Cache::get('slug'););
}
```

Then just place that in your route file, or perhaps your base controller constructor, where ever you want it.

Then when you first get given the slug:

```
Cache::put('slug', $slug, 60); //60 minutes
```

Comment: but is it valid through multiple requests?

Comment: No - but you can just cache it?